# How to read taxonomy in loop?

Tags: loop

How to read taxonomy in loop? Here is the code to explain better:

```php
    <?php $term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );

 $query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'recipe',
    'meta_key' => 'recipe_star_rating',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
   /// 'taxonomy' => $term->slug,
));

$counter = 0;



 global $wp_query;
       
      $total_results = $query ->found_posts;

      echo '<h2>"'.$term->name . '" Recipes</h2>';
      
      echo '<h4 class="tcount">'. $total_results . ' results</h4>';    ?>
      
     <hr class="aloha" />

<?php while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); $counter++;  ?>


    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <?php echo Chefscuisine_Template_Loader::load( 'recipes/grid' ); $counter++; ?>
    </div>
        
     
            
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        
          <? if ($counter % 4 === 0) { 
                echo '<div class="midad">Advert 336x280px Here!</div>';
            } ?>
```

So I got listing, but does not read difficulty - it can be easy, difficult, average.

Comment: `'taxonomies' => $term,` - that isn't the correct way to add taxonomy query to `WP_Query`, but, on what page are you doing the `new WP_Query` call? Because if you're doing that on an archive page (e.g. `example.com/category/foo` for the default `category` taxonomy), then that's a bad practice that could lead to pagination issues, among others.

Comment: Unless if you're just trying to have a separate section alongside the main loop/query? And actually, your code did not really *explain* what are you really trying to do, so could you please clarify that, specifically what did you mean by "read taxonomy in loop"?

Comment: I agree with Sally, I read the question and the code but did not understand what you were asking for. It's not clear where the code comes from or what you want to do. Please add more information/context to your question by using the Edit link underneath the list of tags to improve your question so that it can be understood

Answer (score 0):

I got it working here is the code:

```
...

<?php 

$term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ), get_queried_object()->term_id );

// $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'recipe',
    'meta_key' => 'recipe_star_rating',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
   //  'paged' => $paged,
    'status' => get_query_var( 'term' ),
));

global $wp_query;

$total_results = $query ->found_posts;

echo '<h2>"'.$term->name . '" Recipes</h2>';
      
echo '<h4 class="tcount">'. $total_results . ' results</h4>';  
      
?>

<hr class="aloha" />
    
<?php $counter = 0;  while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); $counter++;  ?>

<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<?php echo Chefscuisine_Template_Loader::load( 'recipes/grid' ); // $counter++; ?>
</div>
        
<? if ($counter % 3 === 0) { 
                echo '<div class="midad">Advert 336x280px Here!</div>';
} ?>
            
            
<?php endwhile; ?>

</div>
...
```